# PDFBox UTF16 letters

Tags: pdfbox, letters

Does any body can help me with letter issue in PDFBox I'm trying to print letter "ń" ( polish letter ) and I'm getting something like **þÿ J . Dı B R O W 2S0 :K0 3I**.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

I came upon the same problem with Bulgarian. In short, I think there isn't an easy solution. Basically you need a utf font. If you use one of the standard 14 type1 fonts (like Helvetica or Courier) - they only support the basic latin alpabet, so they can't do the job. You could load a truetype utf font but pdfbox has a hardocded WinAsciiEncoding for all truetype (type1 as well) fonts which is wrong. You could do what Open office does as far as I can see - create a subset of a font so that you don't embed the whole font file in the pdf. Unfortunately this functionality is missing in pdfbox but there is a Jira and more information:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-922
If you find a good solution please share!

Answer (score 0):

you can change it to unicode characters into LegacyPDFStream Engine  java class

Comment: That is for text extraction. I think the OP had problems with PDF creation. Which have been solved with the release of PDFBox 2.0.